# Calculating essential matrix using OpenCV - what did I do wrong

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, 3d-reconstruction

I'm currently trying to calculate the essential matrices of 3 cameras, based on a fourth camera which I use as the "base camera". I am using OpenCV to calculate the essential matrix.

Even though my points seem to be correct, when I reconstruct the pose of the camera it doesn't make any sense. For example two of the output translation vectors are (0, 0, -1).
I suspect I am somehow messing up the enforcing of the internal constrains, but don't know how.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and hope somebody can help me :)

```
basePoints = np.loadtxt("data/calibration/fundamental_matrix/resulting_data/camera0/extracted_points/points.txt")

    for c in range(1, cameras):
        print(f"caculating essential matrix for camera {c}")
        cameraPoints = np.loadtxt(f"data/calibration/fundamental_matrix/resulting_data/camera{c}/extracted_points/points.txt")
        cm = np.loadtxt(f"data/calibration/camera_matrix/resulting_data/camera{c}/cmatrix.txt")
        em, mask = cv.findEssentialMat(basePoints, cameraPoints, cm, cv.RANSAC, 0.9999, 1)
        print(f"essential matrix {c} 1:")
        print(em)
        print(f"enforcing internal constrain of essential matrix for camera {c}")
        u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(em)
        em = u.T * np.diag([1, 1, 0]) * v
        print(f"enforced essential matrix {c} :")
        print(em)
        np.savetxt(f"data/calibration/essential_matrix_and_pose/resulting_data/camera{c}/ematrix.txt", em)
```

[image: view from "base camera"]

[image: view from first camera]

[image: extracted points from "base cam"]

Here are some normalized sample points of my data:

base camera:

```
6.899999999999999467e-01 4.066666666666666347e-02
6.899999999999999467e-01 4.066666666666666347e-02
6.913333333333333552e-01 4.066666666666666347e-02
6.919999999999999485e-01 4.066666666666666347e-02
6.946666666666666545e-01 4.066666666666666347e-02
6.986666666666666581e-01 4.133333333333333304e-02
7.026666666666666616e-01 4.133333333333333304e-02
7.073333333333332584e-01 4.199999999999999567e-02
7.119999999999999662e-01 4.266666666666666524e-02
7.173333333333332673e-01 4.466666666666666702e-02
```

first camera:

```
3.893333333333333091e-01 6.600000000000000311e-02
3.900000000000000133e-01 6.600000000000000311e-02
3.906666666666666621e-01 6.533333333333332660e-02
3.913333333333333108e-01 6.466666666666666397e-02
3.939999999999999614e-01 6.333333333333332482e-02
3.979999999999999649e-01 6.066666666666666735e-02
4.019999999999999685e-01 5.799999999999999600e-02
4.066666666666666763e-01 5.600000000000000117e-02
4.119999999999999774e-01 5.333333333333332982e-02
4.186666666666666314e-01 5.133333333333333498e-02
```

camera matrix:

```
8.830992819912107734e+02 0.000000000000000000e+00 8.279597017259351333e+02
0.000000000000000000e+00 8.678798953432041117e+02 5.529431146654350187e+02
0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00
```

Comment: Need a minimal reproducible sample. From the OpenCV image calibration cpp file. I found no issue in finding the correct pose based on sets of chessboard correspondences. There is a high chance your input data has some issue.

Comment: I used simulated images I rendered in Blender, so my Points are very easy to distiguish from the background. I plotted the points to an image and they seemed fine. I am not sure how i can give you a reproducable sample, since the whole program is a bit long to add to a post. Maybe i can upload the project to github or something?

Comment: show the simulated image pair and the selected coordinates.  or if you really have problem. you may try opencv calibration sample with the given sample data that will show you it works.

Comment: The first two images are calibration images for the base and the first cam. I have 100 of these. In the third image I plotted all the extracted points of the base camera. Those plotted points coincide with my simulated points.

Comment: selected coordinates?

Comment: base cam:
- normalized coordinates: (0.69|0.04066666666666666)
- real coordinates: (1035.0|61.0)
first cam:
- normalized coordinates: (0.3893333333333333|0.066)
- real coordinates: (584.0|99.00000000000001)

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga13f7e34de8fa516a686a56af1196247f     Array of N (N >= 5) 2D points from the first image. The point coordinates should be floating-point .   p5p. need at least 5.    I suggest go thought this https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html   to understand what do i mean by giving out the coordinate   which is src_pts  and  dst_pts in the example that i give

Comment: As far as I understand the src_pts are the points of my base cam and the dst_pts are the ones of my first cam, since i want to get the relative translation and rotation between them. Thats what i gave you in my last comment. I only gave you one of the point pairs, since i don't know how i could post two 100-element lists.

Comment: try to post 10 sample pairs. then we try to run based on this 10 pair

Comment: In my edit I added 10 sample pairs. They are normalized, let me know if I should give you the real image coordinates instead.

Comment: I never use normalized coordinates in the find p5p function. that might be the issue. whats the camera matrix?   is the focal  length in this camera matrix 1?

Comment: I didn't use normalization at the start. I implemented it to try and fix the problem which didn't work. I since then tried with and without. I added my camera matrix in the edit. Since the bottom right value is 1 i think that means my focal length is 1 yes.

Comment: nope that 1 is just for mathmatical compatibility. if you are using the normalized coordinate. then  883 should be normalized to 1 as well. i`ll try with you data when i back to lab.

Comment: I got some progress. When i removed the normalization and the enforcing of the internal constraint of the essential matrix, I got some translation vectors which somewhat represent the expected result. However my calculated error of the essential matrix is now over 30000. When I use the enforcing the error goes even higher and my results don't make sense again.

Answer (score 0):

Im` running with your data. But I encounter an issue where one of the points is missing in the drawing, then I look closer at your data.

base camera: point 1 and point 2 are identical which may yield matrix rank deficiency. Any co-linear pattern may cause rank deficiency. So pick points that is far away enough to ensure good compliance of epi-polar constraint

6.899999999999999467e-01 4.066666666666666347e-02

6.899999999999999467e-01 4.066666666666666347e-02

So i used  all of your 10 points. it turns out to have a valid calculation output. Meaning no [0,0,-1]

E [0.3020626878915512, -0.5152322345602659, -0.2301187342264469;
0.4556056566568232, 0.3185648205272573, 0.2998902206892574;
0.4240482789694776, -0.09650735405531717, 0.04705772208405343]
rotation [0.8636412841012429, 0.5040818976266604, 0.005017258321223739;
-0.4976326944200423, 0.854097413780324, -0.1512590797870002;
-0.0805321913287191, 0.1281368341222253, 0.9884814201091126]
rodrigues [0.146966997598983, 0.04500046398453182, -0.5269188943544275]
translation [-0.4250629252517419, -0.4494569974529025, 0.7856907260602315]

here is my code to get this.

```
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;

using namespace cv;
#define M_PI acos(-1.0)
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<cv::Point2d> Frame_A_points;
    std::vector<cv::Point2d> Frame_B_points;

    double focalx = 883.;
    double focaly = 867.;

    double focal = (focalx+focaly)/2;
       
    cv::Point2d camera_principal_point(827, 552);    
    Frame_A_points.push_back(Point2d(6.899999999999999467e-01*focalx, 4.066666666666666347e-02*focaly));
    Frame_A_points.push_back(Point2d(6.899999999999999467e-01*focalx, 4.066666666666666347e-02*focaly));
    Frame_A_points.push_back(Point2d(6.913333333333333552e-01*focalx, 4.066666666666666347e-02*focaly));    
    Frame_A_points.push_back(Point2d(6.919999999999999485e-01*focalx, 4.066666666666666347e-02*focaly));
    Frame_A_points.push_back(Point2d(6.946666666666666545e-01*focalx, 4.066666666666666347e-02*focaly)); 
    Frame_A_points.push_back(Point2d(6.986666666666666581e-01*focalx, 4.133333333333333304e-02*focaly));
    Frame_A_points.push_back(Point2d(7.026666666666666616e-01*focalx, 4.133333333333333304e-02*focaly)); 
    Frame_A_points.push_back(Point2d(7.073333333333332584e-01*focalx, 4.199999999999999567e-02*focaly));
    Frame_A_points.push_back(Point2d(7.119999999999999662e-01*focalx, 4.266666666666666524e-02*focaly)); 
    Frame_A_points.push_back(Point2d(7.173333333333332673e-01*focalx, 4.466666666666666702e-02*focaly));

    Frame_B_points.push_back(Point2d(3.893333333333333091e-01*focalx, 6.600000000000000311e-02*focaly));
    Frame_B_points.push_back(Point2d(3.900000000000000133e-01*focalx, 6.600000000000000311e-02*focaly));    
    Frame_B_points.push_back(Point2d(3.906666666666666621e-01*focalx, 6.533333333333332660e-02*focaly));
    Frame_B_points.push_back(Point2d(3.913333333333333108e-01*focalx, 6.466666666666666397e-02*focaly)); 
    Frame_B_points.push_back(Point2d(3.939999999999999614e-01*focalx, 6.333333333333332482e-02*focaly));
    Frame_B_points.push_back(Point2d(3.979999999999999649e-01*focalx, 6.066666666666666735e-02*focaly)); 
    Frame_B_points.push_back(Point2d(4.019999999999999685e-01*focalx, 5.799999999999999600e-02*focaly));
    Frame_B_points.push_back(Point2d(4.066666666666666763e-01*focalx, 5.600000000000000117e-02*focaly)); 
    Frame_B_points.push_back(Point2d(4.119999999999999774e-01*focalx, 5.333333333333332982e-02*focaly));
    Frame_B_points.push_back(Point2d(4.186666666666666314e-01*focalx, 5.133333333333333498e-02*focaly));



    std::cout<< Frame_A_points<< std::endl;


    Mat x(1000, 1000, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    Mat y(1000, 1000, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));
    double d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Frame_A_points.size(); i++)
    {
        circle(x, Frame_A_points[i], 1, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
        circle(y, Frame_B_points[i], 1, Scalar(0, 255, 255));
        d += norm(Frame_A_points[i] - Frame_B_points[i]);
    }
    cout << "Mean marker distance" << d / Frame_A_points.size() << "\n";
   

 
        cv::Mat essential_matrix = cv::findEssentialMat(Frame_A_points, Frame_B_points, focal, camera_principal_point, cv::LMEDS);
        cv::Mat rotation=Mat::zeros(3,3,CV_64F), translation=Mat::zeros(3, 1, CV_64F);
        cv::recoverPose(essential_matrix, Frame_A_points, Frame_B_points, rotation, translation, focal, camera_principal_point);
        cv::Mat rot(3, 1, CV_64F);
        cv::Rodrigues(rotation, rot);
        //cout << "Essai " << i << " with " << Frame_A_points.size() << "points\n"; 
        std::cout << "E " << essential_matrix << std::endl;
        std::cout << "rotation " << rotation << std::endl;
        std::cout << "rodrigues " << rot.t() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "translation " << translation.t() << std::endl;
     imshow("ptx", x);
    imshow("pty", y);
    waitKey();
}
```

Noted that

The translation vector is only up to scale. means you cant recover the full pose without depth Z .

You can take reference to how other people get the up to scale translation vector by multipling the estimated T with ground truth scale

https://github.com/alishobeiri/Monocular-Video-Odometery/blob/master/monovideoodometery.py

```
    if self.id < 2:
        E, _ = cv2.findEssentialMat(self.good_new, self.good_old, self.focal, self.pp, cv2.RANSAC, 0.999, 1.0, None)
        _, self.R, self.t, _ = cv2.recoverPose(E, self.good_old, self.good_new, self.R, self.t, self.focal, self.pp, None)
    else:
        E, _ = cv2.findEssentialMat(self.good_new, self.good_old, self.focal, self.pp, cv2.RANSAC, 0.999, 1.0, None)
        _, R, t, _ = cv2.recoverPose(E, self.good_old, self.good_new, self.R.copy(), self.t.copy(), self.focal, self.pp, None)

        absolute_scale = self.get_absolute_scale()
        if (absolute_scale > 0.1 and abs(t[2][0]) > abs(t[0][0]) and abs(t[2][0]) > abs(t[1][0])):
            self.t = self.t + absolute_scale*self.R.dot(t)
            self.R = R.dot(self.R)
```